# Two power icons in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, system-tray, notification-area

In Xubuntu 16.04.3 (and several previous versions aswell) it is not possible to have no power icon in the notification area.

A power icon is displayed even though 'Show system tray icon' is unchecked in Xfce Power Manager.

When 'Show system tray icon' is checked, there are two power icons displayed.

(See screenshots)

I've searched and I can't find any information related to this in Xubuntu/Xfce.

Is there a way to fix or work around this bug?

[image: 'Show system tray icon' unchecked]
[image: 'Show system tray icon' checked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right-click on the panel (taskbar) opens a menu. Choose `Panel > Panel Preferences...` and the panel preferences window will open. In this window choose the `Items`-tab, look for the `Power Manger Plugin` and remove it with a click on the `-`-button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Do you know whether this bug been reported?

Comment: I myself never considered this as a bug., in my case I get icons with a different look, but this may depend on the icon theme. both icons provide the same functions, but one icon comes from a `panel plugin`, the other from an `indicator plugin`. It's redundant, only one of them would be enough and one could consider it as a bug, I don't know if anyone  reported it as a bug. Both plugins work properly, so none of them is buggy...

Comment: Seems it's never reported as a bug as you can see at https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&no_redirect=1&order=relevance%20desc&product=Xfce4-power-manager&query_format=specific