# Why am I seeing two nm-applets in Xubuntu panel?

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, xfce

Here is the screenshot of it.

[image: link]

I am seeing this problem after I rebooted my PC.

Xubuntu Version 20.04.1

Comment: It is not clear from the question if another applet comes back on every reboot after you remove one of them

Comment: No, I have just seen such a phenomenon, and have not restarted again yet

Comment: See this question. https://askubuntu.com/q/974755/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two power icons in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974755/two-power-icons-in-xubuntu)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, the problem was fixed

Comment: There exist several panel plugins which do pretty the same thing, take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1119638/590937).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on one of the network manager applets, and remove the applet.

Comment: I am able to remove one applet, and not the other, not even move it.